# Can't get a JPEG Image to display in JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am trying to get a background Image to display on a `JFrame` for a small game I'm programming.  The image is a .jpg and I keep getting these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
     at web.game.Base.<init>(Base.java:45)
     at web.game.Base.main(Base.java:61)
```

And my code is:

```
Image myimage;

public Base() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("myimage.jpg"));
    myimage = ii.getImage();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(myimage, 10, 10, null);
```

Comment: It seems that Java can't find your resource, and is returning a null for `this.getClass().getResource("myimage.jpg")`. Is your IDE copying the resources? Are you sure thats the proper path for it?

Comment: The obvious thing is the reference to the image is `null`.  This would suggest that `myimage.jpg` doesn't live in the same location as the class you are trying to read it from.  Where does the image exist?

Comment: okay so I'm using netbeans and myimage.jpg exists in the root of the project folder.  I am pretty sure that's where it should be because I have an Audio file that will play from the same place with the same path as myimage.jpg

Comment: Try `ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/myimage.jpg"))` instead, this will at least throw an exception if something goes wrong

Comment: `"I am pretty sure that's where it should be..."` make no assumptions until your code starts working.

Comment: @TonyC : Please have a look at this thread, [adding a package for the image](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html#package), you can see more information on the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) part of the embedded-resource tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons you might have problems.  The most obvious begin, the image doesn't exist (or at least doesn't exist where you think it does)

```
private BufferedImage myImage;

public Board() { 
    try {
        myimage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/myimage")); 
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (myImage != null) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
        g2d.drawImage(myimage, 10, 10, this); 
        System.out.println("Background Image"); 
    }
}
```

You may find [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) of some use.

When using `getResource` you have two (basic) choices.  Relative or absolute.

With a relative path, the class loader will start searching based on the context of the class.  So if you image is in the root folder of your project, but your class is in sub folder (of packages), then a relative path won't work, because the class loader will start search from where the class resides.

An absolute path will allow you to search from the root of the classpath, which is going to be more helpful, especially in your case.

Try something like this and see what you get..

```
System.out.println(TestReference.class.getResource("myimage.jpg"));
System.out.println(TestReference.class.getResource("/myimage.jpg"));
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, my bad, copy and pasted the OPs code on the iPad, so wasn't really paying attention

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer that did the trick it wanted the image in the same folder as the source.  Looks like I keep messing up the simple stuff.

Comment: *"..the OPs code on the iPad"*  Ah.  Having tried, once, to interact with SO on a mobile phone, I can relate.